# Passwords and cookies when running Chrome remotely

Tags: google-chrome, ssh, passwords

I use Ubuntu 23.10. I usually use Google Chrome on my desktop PC, and I have my passwords saved in Google Password Manager. This works fine. But when I login remotely from my laptop (also running Ubuntu) the button for Google Password Manager shows an empty password list.

Why is that? Is there any way to see my passwords when I login remotely?

By logging in remotely, I mean this:

- On my laptop, in the Bash shell, I run `ssh -X user@host`.
- Then at the Bash prompt (belonging to the desktop PC I've logged into), I run `google-chrome`.

Also, I noticed that my normal cookies are absent when I login remotely. Does Google use a different cookie location when logged in through ssh -X than when used on the local machine?